# How to use Room with RecyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I need to save tasks in my todo app and load them in recycler view as well. But I'm new and cannot figure out with it. I wanna use data class instead of view model. How can I use tasks from database and show it on the screen ? I don't know what to do. Help me plz

Todo

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.taskmaster

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import java.io.Serializable

@Entity
data class Todo(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id:Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") var title:String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description") var description:String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date") var date: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "isChecked") var isChecked:Boolean=false
) : Serializable
```

TodoDao

```
@Dao
interface TodoDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM todo")
    fun getAllTasks(): LiveData<List<Todo>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun saveTodo(todo: Todo)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(todo: Todo)
}
```

RoomDatabase

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = [Todo::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun todoDao(): TodoDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var instance: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase?{
            if (AppDatabase == null){
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,
                    AppDatabase::class.java, "roomDatabase")
                    .build()
            }
            return instance
        }
    }
}
```

TaskListFragment

```
class TaskListFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_task_list) {
    private lateinit var todoAdapter: TodoAdapter
    private var _binding: FragmentTaskListBinding? = null
    private lateinit var todoDao: TodoDao
    private val binding: FragmentTaskListBinding
        get() = checkNotNull(_binding)
    private var todos: MutableList<Todo> = mutableListOf()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val appDatabase = AppDatabase.getInstance(this.requireActivity())
        todoDao = appDatabase.todoDao()
        val task = Todo(title = "Заголовок", description = "Описание", date="1/12/23", isChecked = false)
        GlobalScope.launch {
            todoDao.insert(task)
        }
        todoDao.getAllTasks().observe(this, Observer { tasks ->
        })
    }
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentTaskListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        todoAdapter = TodoAdapter(todos)
        binding.rvTodoItems.adapter = todoAdapter
        binding.rvTodoItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.activity)
        binding.btnAddTodo.setOnClickListener {
            NewTaskSheet().show(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, "NewTaskTag")
        }
        requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener(
            "requestKey",
            this
        ) { requestKey, bundle ->
            val newTodo = bundle.getSerializable("bundleKey") as Todo
            todos.add(newTodo)
            todoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

TodoAdapter

```
lass TodoAdapter(
    private var todos: MutableList<Todo>
):RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>() {

    class TodoViewHolder( ItemTodoBinding: ItemTodoBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(ItemTodoBinding.root)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {

        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val ItemTodoBinding = ItemTodoBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)

        return TodoViewHolder(
            return TodoViewHolder(ItemTodoBinding)
        )
    }


    private fun toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle: TextView, isChecked:Boolean){
        if(isChecked){
            tvTodoTitle.paintFlags = tvTodoTitle.paintFlags or STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
        }else{
            tvTodoTitle.paintFlags = tvTodoTitle.paintFlags and STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
          val curTodo = todos[position]
          holder.itemView.apply{
              val tvTodoTitle = findViewById(R.id.tvTodoTitle) as TextView
              val tvTodoDate = findViewById(R.id.tvTodoDate) as TextView
              tvTodoTitle.text = curTodo.title
              tvTodoDate.text=curTodo.date
              val cbDone = findViewById(R.id.cbDone) as CheckBox
              cbDone.isChecked = curTodo.isChecked
              toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle, curTodo.isChecked)
              cbDone.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                  toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle, isChecked)
                  curTodo.isChecked = !curTodo.isChecked
              }

              cbDone.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener{
                      todos.removeAll { todo ->
                          todo.isChecked

                      }
                      notifyDataSetChanged()
              })
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
          return todos.size
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you say you want to use a data class instead of view model? There's no comparison. You need both to build something that works. I recommend going through the "Room with a View" tutorial from the Android developer web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After initializing `todoAdapter`, observe LiveData of `todoDao.getAllTasks()` with a lambda that update the recycler view.

```kotlin
todoAdapter = TodoAdapter(todos)
todoDao.getAllTasks().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { tasks ->
    // update the recycler view
    // invoke adapter's update function
    todoAdapter.submitList(tasks)
})
```

Comment: I don't understand how to update the recycler view using this. How to connect database and it ?

Comment: @ВладиславаЧеркасова Observe Dao's `LiveData` and update the recycler view with invoking the update function of `TodoAdapter` you defined.
Dao's `LiveData` will emit a new value when there is any change and if you're observing the `LiveData`, updated database values will be applied to the recycler view.